# Swarm - when update of service is correctly done

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Let's look at following command:
`docker service update --detach=true --force service_name`

Let's consider log of this operation:

```
service_name
overall progress: 1 out of 1 tasks 
1/1: running   [==================================================>] 
verify: Waiting 1 seconds to verify that tasks are stable...
```

And now, my question is: From what swarm know that task is stable and ready for running?
After all, we can launch any service in swarm and the question is how it recognize that
it is ok to say that update succeeded and service is ready for working. Any materials or references about these things?

Comment: Look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: Could you be more precisely?

Comment: if the process inside the container won't die in 5 seconds and the healtcheck is OK then it's stable.

Comment: How dockerd is able to check if process is living? I know that it is possible in UNIX systems when parent check liveness of its child. However we have no child-parent relation here.

Comment: docker has its ID because it is starting it.

Comment: Do you mean ID of process in system? (We know that service is container, container is process) ? Then, given PID, are we able to recognize if process is living or not? It seems to be natually, for example with (h)top tool. Yeah? In other words I don't understand: `docker has its ID because it is starting it` What is ID exactly? After all, each (not only starter) can know PIDs of processes.

Comment: @Developer If you perform `docker inspect <container name>`, you will see that Docker knows the PID of the container process (under State). It also has it's Status.

Answer (score 0):

for Docker, "tasks are stable" is the opposite to "overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks".
Remember that, for a container is UP, you need run a process/task (al least one).
this is the reason why docker need verify if one task are running Ok.

Regards